# Undefined variable: page (View: D:\wamp\www\laraangular\resources\views\site\about.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I use laravel with CMS voyager, I want to recover page data but I can not get it. I am sure about the name slug.

```
public function about()
{
    $page = Page::where('slug', 'propos')->first();

    return view('site.about', ['page', $page]);
}
```

Comment: Use `dd($page);` after setting `$page` and see if it contains data

Comment: yes i get my data of page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `['page',  $page]` but it must be `['page' => $page]`

```
public function about(){
    $page = Page::where('slug','propos')->first();
    return view('site.about',['page' => $page]);
    // or return view('site.about', compact('page'));
    // or return view('site.about')->with('page', $page);
}
```